# using xpathSApply in R to calculate mean

Tags: xml, r

I have difficulties in applying the xpathSApply to calculate mean for temperature. The XML can be obtained from here, http://www.yr.no/place/Malaysia/Kuala_Lumpur/Kuala_Lumpur/forecast_hour_by_hour.xml

My R Code:

```
library(XML)
fileURL<-"http://www.yr.no/place/Malaysia/Kuala_Lumpur/Kuala_Lumpur/forecast_hour_by_hour.xml"
doc <- xmlTreeParse(fileURL, useInternal=TRUE)
rootNode <- xmlRoot(doc)
xmlName(rootNode)
mean(xpathSApply(rootNode, "//temperature", xmlValue))
```

The XML is as shown below

```
<weatherdata>
<location>
<name>Kuala Lumpur</name>
<type>Capital</type>
<country>Malaysia</country>
<timezone id="Asia/Kuala_Lumpur" utcoffsetMinutes="480"/>
<location altitude="56" latitude="3.1412" longitude="101.68653" geobase="geonames" geobaseid="1735161"/>
</location>
<credit>
<!--
In order to use the free weather data from yr no, you HAVE to display 
the following text clearly visible on your web page. The text should be a 
link to the specified URL.
-->
<!--
Please read more about our conditions and guidelines at http://om.yr.no/verdata/  English explanation at http://om.yr.no/verdata/free-weather-data/
-->
<link text="Weather forecast from yr.no, delivered by the Norwegian Meteorological Institute and the NRK" url="http://www.yr.no/place/Malaysia/Kuala_Lumpur/Kuala_Lumpur/"/>
</credit>
<links>
<link id="xmlSource" url="http://www.yr.no/place/Malaysia/Kuala_Lumpur/Kuala_Lumpur/forecast.xml"/>
<link id="xmlSourceHourByHour" url="http://www.yr.no/place/Malaysia/Kuala_Lumpur/Kuala_Lumpur/forecast_hour_by_hour.xml"/>
<link id="overview" url="http://www.yr.no/place/Malaysia/Kuala_Lumpur/Kuala_Lumpur/"/>
<link id="hourByHour" url="http://www.yr.no/place/Malaysia/Kuala_Lumpur/Kuala_Lumpur/hour_by_hour"/>
<link id="longTermForecast" url="http://www.yr.no/place/Malaysia/Kuala_Lumpur/Kuala_Lumpur/long"/>
</links>
<meta>
<lastupdate>2015-06-26T15:40:08</lastupdate>
<nextupdate>2015-06-27T04:00:00</nextupdate>
</meta>
<sun rise="2015-06-26T07:06:55" set="2015-06-26T19:25:04"/>
<forecast>
<tabular>
<time from="2015-06-26T17:00:00" to="2015-06-26T20:00:00">
<!--
Valid from 2015-06-26T17:00:00 to 2015-06-26T20:00:00 
-->
<symbol number="1" numberEx="1" name="Clear sky" var="01d"/>
<precipitation value="0"/>
<!--  Valid at 2015-06-26T17:00:00  -->
<windDirection deg="163.0" code="SSE" name="South-southeast"/>
<windSpeed mps="2.9" name="Light breeze"/>
<temperature unit="celsius" value="31"/>
<pressure unit="hPa" value="1008.1"/>
</time>
<time from="2015-06-26T20:00:00" to="2015-06-26T23:00:00">
<!--
Valid from 2015-06-26T20:00:00 to 2015-06-26T23:00:00 
-->
<symbol number="1" numberEx="1" name="Clear sky" var="mf/01n.31"/>
<precipitation value="0"/>
<!--  Valid at 2015-06-26T20:00:00  -->
<windDirection deg="143.3" code="SE" name="Southeast"/>
<windSpeed mps="1.2" name="Light air"/>
<temperature unit="celsius" value="29"/>
<pressure unit="hPa" value="1009.4"/>
</time>
</time>
</tabular>
</forecast>
</weatherdata>'
```

Am I doing the right thing here? Or I am getting it all wrong? I am sorry if this is a repeated question.

Comment: Try `mean(xpathSApply(doc, "//temperature/@value", as.numeric))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two or three issues:

1. Function `xPathSApply` expects XML document as a first argument. Use  `xpathSApply(doc, ...)` instead of `xpathSApply(rootNode, ...)`
2. The temperature value is in the attribute of the element. You can get it with xpath expression (element/@attribute):

   ```
   temp <- xpathSApply(doc, "//temperature/@value", as.numeric)
   ```

   or using `xmlGetAttr` function:

   ```
   temp <- as.numeric(xpathSApply(doc, "//temperature", xmlGetAttr, "value"))
   ```
3. Note the `is.numeric` call in both alternatives. You have to use a numeric vector with the `mean` function.

Answer (score 1):

It is working this way:

```
library(XML)
fileURL<-"http://www.yr.no/place/Malaysia/Kuala_Lumpur/Kuala_Lumpur/forecast_hour_by_hour.xml"
doc <- xmlTreeParse(fileURL, useInternal=TRUE)
rootNode <- xmlRoot(doc)
xmlName(rootNode)
mean(xpathSApply(doc, "//temperature/@value", as.numeric))
```

result is as below:

```
[1] "weatherdata"
[1] 27.6875
```